# Cassandra node was unable to process requests for a couple of minutes, log reported "Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage"

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra node was unable to process requests for couple of minutes, where we see this log "Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage"

The application faced timeouts for a couple of minutes and when I checked in the logs I see continuous logging of the below messages for 2 minutes, can you please explain what could this mean?

LOG -

```
INFO  [ReadStage-545] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,461 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-545
INFO  [ReadStage-566] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,880 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-566
INFO  [ReadStage-568] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,880 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-568
INFO  [ReadStage-571] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,880 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-571
INFO  [ReadStage-567] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,880 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-567
INFO  [ReadStage-572] 2023-01-07 15:00:01,928 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-572
INFO  [ReadStage-577] 2023-01-07 15:00:02,036 TermIterator.java:53 - Search Concurrency Factor is set to 1 for ReadStage-577
```

Cluster info -

Multi DC architecture, the issue was found only on a single node for a couple of minutes.
Version - Apache 3.11.8
4 node DC with replication factor 3, Local quorum consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Those log entries don't indicate any problem at all which is why there were logged at `INFO` log level instead of `WARN` or `ERROR`.

You didn't indicate how you knew that the node was not able to process requests so it is almost impossible to provide guidance on how you would investigate further.

If you update the body of your question with additional details, I'd be happy to review it again. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!